# OWL : how to write class axiom that says "hasValue X from {A,B,C,D} disjointWith hasValue ({A,B,C,D} - X), where X is one of class from A,B,C,D

Tags: rdf, owl, semantic-web, protege

I want to write a general class axiom that says

> if something hasValue (property) from one of the class {A,B,C,D} then
> it can't have a different hasValue from rest of the remaining classes.

"hasValue some {A,B,C,D} disjointWith hasValue some ({A,B,C,D} - X)",
where X is one of the class before disjointWith.

Basically union of folling 4 statements, but in one statement.

- "hasValue some A disjointWith hasValue some {B,C,D}"
- "hasValue some B disjointWith hasValue some {A,C,D}"
- "hasValue some C disjointWith hasValue some {A,B,D}"
- "hasValue some D disjointWith hasValue some {A,B,C}"

Comment: not possible as you don't have variables in OWL, i.e. can't refer to something in the class expression of the left-side of the axiom. I think this wouldn't even be possible in first order logic

Answer (score 0):

As @UninformedUser has already commented, what you describe in the first part of your question isn't possible in OWL (restricting one property assertion based on the filler of another property isn't supported).

However in the second part you list four class restrictions and ask how to do that in one statement - you can just intersect the four class expressions, although that wouldn't achieve your primary objective.

Another partial solution: declare A, B, C, D members of a disjoint union and declare a property with the disjoint union as range and a cardinality restriction of 1, so that only one property assertion can be made. Two property assertions would force the fillers to be the same individual, and if the fillers belong to, e.g., A and B,